# Styling an ordered list with background image

Tags: html, css

```css
.color-overlap-right {
 background-color : #d93;
 margin-right : -25%;
}

ol {
 margin-left:0; 
 padding-left:0; 
 counter-reset: ol-item
}

ol li {
 margin-left:0; 
 padding-left:0; 
 list-style-type:none; 
 counter-increment: ol-item;
}

ol li:before {
 content:counter(ol-item) " ";
 background-image: url('../img/square.png');
 background-position: 0 -20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<div class="container">
  <div class="color-overlap-right">
   <div class="left-text">
        <ol style="list-style: aliceblue;">
            <li>Earn</li>
      <li>Transfer</li>
      <li>Apply</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a Ordered list in HTML which looks like this

[image]

This should have ordered list without a "dot"
Numbering should be in italics and font-size customizable.
should either have a background image/color as displayed. Can someone please help? I am currently able to remove the "dot" and add background color. However i am not able to adjust the margins between background image and number such that it looks similar to what is shown below. Can someone help?

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to add some **CSS** property to achieve this design, 
add these css in **`ol li:before`** selector

```
ol li:before {
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-shadow: -4px 2px 7px #504747;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**Edited**

```
/*This is for square box*/
    ol li:after{
      content: "";
      display: block;
      background: #ab6b0b;
      position: absolute;
      top: 17px;
      left: 3px;
      height: 18px;
      width: 17px;
    }
```

Result would be like this:

[image]

You can modify font colors and shadow as per your UI

```css
.color-overlap-right {
  background-color: #d93;
  margin-right: -25%;
}

ol {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  counter-reset: ol-item
}

ol li {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: ol-item;
  position: relative;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(ol-item) " ";
  background-image: url('../img/square.png');
  background-position: 0 -20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-shadow: -4px 2px 7px #504747;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ol li:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #ab6b0b;
    position: absolute;
    top: 17px;
    left: 3px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 17px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<div class="container">
  <div class="color-overlap-right">
    <div class="left-text">
      <ol style="list-style: aliceblue;">
        <li>Earn</li>
        <li>Transfer</li>
        <li>Apply</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted a Square image behind the number and not just a shadow.

Comment: Check the updated answer, you need to modify the square box which is generated in pure `CSS` not image

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="mylist">
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Earn</span></li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Transfer</span></li>
  <li>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><span>Apply</span></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: #d93;
}

.mylist {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.mylist li {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: section;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.mylist li span {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.mylist li div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #D25F15;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.mylist li:before {
  position: relative;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: counter(section) " ";
  margin-left: 12px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/9no97bz0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    background-color : #d93;

}

ol {
    margin-left:0; 
    padding-left:0; 
    counter-reset: ol-item;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: arial;
}

ol li {
    margin-left:0; 
    padding-left:0; 
    list-style-type:none; 
    counter-increment: ol-item;

}

ol li:before {
    font-size:40px;
  background:  #d25f14;
  content: counter(ol-item) ;
  width:28px;
  height:24px;
  overflow:show;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url(place your image here);
  text-align:right;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Use this CSS and make your image the way you want it